# rails print array values within form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm stuck.  On edit I grab a handful of data from the database and print the values in input fields.  That part is working well.  I want to print on the values without using a text field but can't seem to figure out how.

Form:

```
 <%= form_for(@post, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

Currently working for printing my title value from the database into text field:

```
 <%= f.text_field :title, :size => "65%" %>
```

Controller:

```
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

I've tried quite of bit of variations, but I'm a newbie.

```
<%= post.title %>
<%= @post.title %>
<%= f.title %>
<%= :title %>(lol)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: <%= @post.title %> should work. what is your error?

Comment: No value is printed whatsoever when i view the html output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things you can try:

1) Verify that the post with the ID really has a title.

`rails c`, then `p = Post.find_by_id(5)` (assuming that's the `params[:id]`) then check with `p.title`

2) There are 2 ways you can print the title. One way you have already tried `@post.title`. The other way is `f.object.title`. Therefore, only the second of your variations work.

Comment: Thanks for the rails console tip.  I need to start using that.  I know some mysql pretty well but very new to sqlite.  There was no title for the record lol.  Thanks for the sanity check! @post.title on a record with a title prints just fine.

Comment: No problem! Rails console is your friend. :)